# Informatica Upgrade from 9.0.1 to 10.2.0

Tags: upgrade, informatica-powercenter

We are planning to upgrade Informatica Powercenter from 9.0.1 to 10.2.0.Below are few queries regarding the upgradation:

1)What would be hardware configuration required for 10.2.0 for the below scenario:

(a)All Informatica services and repository will be in one node

2)To upgrade from 9.0.1 to 10.2.0 ,we would follow this approach: 9.1.0--> 9.6.0 -->10.2.0 .Is it fine?

3)How many servers would be require to perform this upgradation .Do i need 3 servers each for 9.1.0,9.6.0 ,10.2.0 or 1 new server is sufficient to perform this upgradation? If 3 servers are required,what would be the hardware configuration required to perform this installation for each version(9.1.0,9.6.0,10.2.0)?

4)Any document that can be helpful to perform this upgradation smoothly.

Please respond as early as possible.

Thanks,
Piyush Khurana

Comment: Did you go through any document first? Informatica has made it available on their support website.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Informatica support site and go through the upgrade planner